# How did 'name' become a global variable?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, google-chrome-devtools

Okay so I'm not sure if this is just isolated to Chromes developer tools, but I was toying around with some code I was working on and I realise that a variable, meant to be local, had been created in the global name space called 'name'.

[image]

I removed the bug then opened up Chrome tools to make sure the bug had been fixed. To my surprise I type 'name' into the console and an empty string is returned. After much looking through my code, I realise this isn't caused by me, so I head over to google.com and try again. To my surprise 'name' is a global variable there. After looking around, it appears there is a global variable almost everywhere when looking with Dev tools.

My question is why?

Comment: window is a standard variable/property, referring to the window's name, as used in popups. it also keeps its value as you change domains, unlike any other js variable. it also can only be a string, unlike any other js variable...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name) is a property of the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object, and like all other members of `window`, it's accessible globally.

Comment: Just realised that too... `Object.keys( window ); ` returns an array of all the global variables in a window. Interesting to have a look through. Thanks

Comment: May not be in IE sometimes - before page loaded name could be undefined / reused for something else, but in FF/Chrome exists already during load and cannot be changed to other type.

Answer (score 2):

`name` is equivalent to `window.name` and is often used to modify the name of a window, after the window has been created.

```
var myWindow = window.open("","MsgWindow","width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This window's name is: " + myWindow.name + "</p>");
```