# merging javascript objects to csv format

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, object

I am trying to get an output as like below (expected output), by combining four different data set (data1,data2,data3,data4), 
where all the names to get combined and value to get added.

```
var 
data1 = [{name:"js",value:"20"}],
data2=[{name:"c#",value:10}],
data3=[{name:"ds",value:30}],
data4 = [{name:"java",value:10},{name:"c",value:40}]
```

expected output

```
output = "js-c#-ds-java,70\n\
js-c#-ds-c,100\n"
```

Comment: Where did cash come from? And where is your code?

Comment: unclear how the you get `js-cash-ds-c,100`

Comment: sorry , output = "js-c#-ds-java,70\n\n
js-c#-ds-c,100\n"

Comment: can you cleanup your original question please?  it is formatted poorly and it makes it more difficult for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want so strange inputs then something like this:

```js
var 
data1 = [{name:"js",value:"20"}],
data2=[{name:"c#",value:10}],
data3=[{name:"ds",value:30}],
data4 = [{name:"java",value:10},{name:"c",value:40}]

var item, nameStack = [], sums={}, output = "";
var i=1;
while(item = window["data" + i++]) {
    var dashName = nameStack.join('-'), val;
    if (dashName) {
        val = sums[dashName];
    } else val = 0;
    for(var j in item) {
        var dashName2;
        nameStack.push(item[j].name);
        dashName2 = nameStack.join('-');
        sums[dashName2] = val + parseInt(item[j].value);
        if(item.length > 1) nameStack.pop();
    }
    delete sums[dashName];
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(sums))
for(item in sums) {
   output += item + "," + sums[item] + "\n"
}
console.log(output)
```

Or in case you have kind of array input a bit easier like this:

```js
var 
data = [[{name:"js",value:"20"}],
[{name:"c#",value:10}],
[{name:"ds",value:30}],
[{name:"java",value:10},{name:"c",value:40}]];

var item, nameStack = [], sums={}, output = "";
var i=1;
for(item in data) {
    item = data[item];
    var dashName = nameStack.join('-'), val;
    if (dashName) {
        val = sums[dashName];
    } else val = 0;
    for(var j in item) {
        var dashName2;
        nameStack.push(item[j].name);
        dashName2 = nameStack.join('-');
        sums[dashName2] = val + parseInt(item[j].value);
        if(item.length > 1) nameStack.pop();
    }
    delete sums[dashName];
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(sums))
for(item in sums) {
   output += item + "," + sums[item] + "\n"
}
console.log(output)
```

Mind accept button under voting in case.

Comment: using `eval` is not recommended, you should delete that from your answer.

Comment: Ok, there is another option to access var indirect, but do not suppose someone will have such input anyway ;-)

Comment: hey, have an error --  name.join is not a function

Comment: Sorry - did not noticed there is a global name string in some browsers and you cannot change it to array, now works also in FF, Chrome.

Comment: Explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152141/how-did-name-become-a-global-variable#22152202